# Business Delegate pattern with Spring controllers

Tags: design-patterns

I am using Spring where my Service Implementations are injected inside the Controller classes, Will it be relevant to use the business delegate pattern here, as Service Interface and their injection is already providing a degree of decoupling, where I can modify the Service Implementation.

If yes Should that be a one to one delegate with service interface relationship 
or should I create common delegate for all of the services.

Example

public class MyUIController extends BaseController {

```
private MyService1 myService1;
private MyService2 myService2;
```

...

```
@Autowired
public MyUIController (MyService1 myService1, MyService2 myService2...) {
    super();
    this.myService1= myService1;
    this.myService2= myService2;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of delegate pattern was more prevalent in earlier days with EJB 2. However, with the advent of Spring and dependency injection Business Delegate layer has more or less lost its significance.

If you do use business delegate, you would most likely end-up having a delegate layer which acts as just a pass through layer i.e. all the methods of the delegate layer will be exact replica of your service methods. This is unnecessary. You need not have a delegate layer.